# iOS json not retrieving data from iTunes api

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api, itunes

I am using the following code to try to get the trackName from iTunes API. It should come from this link for example:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=EMINEM&entity=song&limit=3
It keeps returning nothing (label is blank and it is not because the label is too small)

```
- (void)pressSearchKey {
    NSInteger numberOfResults = 3;
    NSString *searchString = self.keyboard.textField.text;

    NSString *encodedSearchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *finalSearchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?term=%@&entity=song&limit=%ld",searchString,numberOfResults];

    NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:finalSearchString];
    dispatch_queue_t iTunesQueryQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(iTunesQueryQueue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:searchURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

        if (data && !error) {
            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

            NSArray *array = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];
            NSArray *arrayTracks;
            for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in array) {
                arrayTracks = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"trackName"];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.keyboard.firstLabel.text = [arrayTracks objectAtIndex:1];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does it output when you log the dictionary called `JSON`?

Comment: @rebello95 I cannot log because this is an extension (custom keyboard), but I can set a label's text to it. When I did `self.keyboard.firstLabel.text = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];` It did not even change the text. And this `self.keyboard.firstLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", JSON];` just made label blank

Comment: try putting a breakpoint above that line and inspecting the element to see its contents. I'm assuming the deserialization failed

Comment: @rebello95 I cannot set breakpoints since this is a custom keyboard.

Comment: @rebello95 Can you make a simple app (with a label and button) where the above code runs when you press a button, and see if you can replicate it?

Comment: I just did. Changed your code to `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?term=%@&entity=song&limit=%i",encodedSearchString,numberOfResults];` and got a valid response for the search "a": `{
    resultCount = 0;
    results =     (
    );
}`

Comment: @rebello95 I tried changing that, but I get an error (Non-ascii characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers)

Comment: Try manually typing it in, something must be off with the copy/paste or formatting on SO comments

Comment: @rebello95 I tried that, but it still brings a blank label. How do I get the trackName from that? Thanks for helping btw, I'm a little short on time

Comment: Well first of all make sure some search results are being returned

Comment: @rebello95 I think they might be, but not in the correct format. Have you been able to get a trackName from what you have?

Comment: Experiment with it in a test project like I did. No, I didn't get any search results

Comment: @rebello95 Ok I tried. Logging `JSON` says there are 0 results. I don't understand how to fix this. The url looks good though.

Comment: @rebello95 I see the problem now. I changed lookup? to search? Now, there is an error with the arrayTracks line (array works)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of problems in this one too.

1. You're never utilizing your `encodedSearchString` when building `finalSearchString`
2. Your example URL calls https://itunes.apple.com/**search** whereas the URL in your code is https://itunes.apple.com/**lookup**. Changing it to **search** returns the expected results.

Fixed:

```
NSInteger numberOfResults = 3;
NSString *searchString = @"EMINEM";

NSString *encodedSearchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *finalSearchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=%@&entity=song&limit=%ld",encodedSearchString,numberOfResults];

NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:finalSearchString];
dispatch_queue_t iTunesQueryQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(iTunesQueryQueue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:searchURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    if (data && !error) {
        NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

        NSArray *array = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];
        NSArray *arrayTracks;
        for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in array) {
            arrayTracks = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"trackName"];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@", [arrayTracks objectAtIndex:1]);
        });
    }
});
```